# JUCE iOS build has no target

Tags: ios, juce

I have code for a VST plugin and need to port some of it to an iOS app.

I have tried building the OSX version and using the `lib.a` and it doesnt work. When I open the iOS version of it, Xcode shows that it is missing the tagret.

[image]

If I copy the code directly into Xcode with all the JUCE modules, and I set the header search paths, I get compilation errors on things like `no such type for String`

After this latest JUCE update, Xcode would give the same errors until I updated the JUCE file itself, so I think the JUCE build settings or configuration of the new version is doing something differently. How can I get this code into a different Xcode project, so that I can use it?

Can I compile it as a library and use the objects through the header?

Answer (score 3):

JUCE is designed to be included in projects generated by the Introjucer / Projucer (the JUCE project management tool). Without this, the correct preprocessor definitions will not be set up.

If you really needed to include JUCE source code inside your program, you could manually set up these preprocessor definitions (take a look at the AppConfig.h header from a generated project to get an idea of how much work this will be), but you'd really be going against the normal "JUCE way".

Simply including the headers and linking against the library will not work without considerable effort, as the include structure is ... odd ... and there isn't any library to link against directly anyway (the generated projects contain all the JUCE source normally, so there's no need).

Adding the JUCE source files (i.e. .cpp and .mm) to be compiled in a project directly will result in compilation errors, as they need to be compiled in a very specific order which is mandated by the header file (the header files `#include` certain implementation files after setting up their dependencies).

In short, if you can at all I would advise generating the project with the Projucer and adding other source files in as you need them, rather than the other way around.

Comment: True, thats a better option. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why the iOS version cannot be built?

Comment: @Helium3 please elaborate - JUCE very much works for iOS :)

Comment: So there is no target when I open the iOS version from Projucer. I dont really want to add an entire iOS projects code into the iOS build version from the Projucer output and add the targets manually etc. I dont know how future proof this is. Currently I just need to be able to add c++ code, which partly relies on JUCE, into an existing iOS project. The other thing is that I am developing a VST/AU plugin that relies on JUCE for the portability, but want to be able to extract the c++ code into the iOS project. There isnt much dependency on JUCE for that code, maybe a few Arrays and small bits

Comment: So rather than modify a separate version just for this, I would like to easily copy/replace that code and compile. You mentioned the AppConfig file, I had a look, lots of defines etc. Is there anything else that is needed to build correctly? If I copy the JuceLibraryCode folder I get weird errors like, "use of undeclared idenifier 'Arrow Button'", "Unknown type name String", "Unknown type name Colour"

Comment: @Helium3  see updated answer :) The JuceLibraryCode folder is normally just a link to another set of files that are to be included by the headers (it's odd, I know).

Comment: Thanks, but I had to ditch JUCE for the iOS project, it's still great for plugins though :)